# Connect Facebook to an app delegate in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift4, xcode10

I think it is a very easy part, but I can`t understand..

I see "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios" and I want to add Facebook login to the project.

However, adding the source code to the App Delegate is difficult.

I added it this simple, but it does not work.

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 
{
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] 
        application:application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

        return YES;
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    openURL:(NSURL *)url
    options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
    {
        BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
        openURL:url
        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
        annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
        ];

        return handled;
    }
}
```

Please tell me where to put the source code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**
This is also for Facebook's current SDK's as of posting date. I would link the Facebook Swift documentation but it hasn't been updated, as SDKApplicationDelegate has been changed to ApplicationDelegate.

In your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add this line:

```
let _ = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

And below the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, add this function:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let appId: String = SDKSettings.appId
         if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" {
              return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
         }
    return false
}
```

For more info :-[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@joshgare/how-to-integrate-the-ios-facebook-sdk-in-swift-4-9c0192ce7dbf)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not write the `Objective C` code in the `Swift` project. Its a pure mistake of programming for `iOS`.

**Connect Your App Delegate**

Add the following to your `AppDelegate` class. This initializes the SDK when your app launches, and lets the SDK handle results from the native Facebook app when you perform a Login or Share action.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

**Recommended**

For installation of Facebook in Swift project please follow

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Go back to Facebook documentation "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios", and use code for Swift, here you have used Objective C code in Swift project.